# Combine list with sublist of different size

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to combine two list of strings into one, where the first list of strings are applied to all items of list 2. The list are always same length, however the sublist of list 2 can contain more than 1 list.

I've tried combining using `zip()`, like this:

```
[str(x)+'_'+str(y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
```

But that does not work when the sublist does not match in length.

Here is an example of what i want to do:

```
list1 = ['H1','H2','H3','H4']
list2 = ['item1',['item2','item3'],['item4','item5','item6'],['item7','item8']]
```

And the output should be:

```
list = ['H1_item1',['H2_item2','H2_item3'],['H3_item4','H3_item5','H3_item6'],['H4_item7','H4_item8']]
```

Comment: Is it only nested one level deep?

Comment: yes, only nested one level deep.

Comment: Why is `item1` not also in its own list?

Comment: Can it has more levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
['%s_%s'%(x,y) if isinstance(y,str) else ['%s_%s'%(x,yi) for yi in y]
     for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
```

This generates:

```
>>> ['%s_%s'%(x,y) if isinstance(y,str) else ['%s_%s'%(x,yi) for yi in y]
...      for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
['H1_item1', ['H2_item2', 'H2_item3'], ['H3_item4', 'H3_item5', 'H3_item6'], ['H4_item7', 'H4_item8']]
```

The code works as follows: we use - like you've done yourself - `zip(list1,list2)` to produce pairs of elements of the two lists. Now for each such pair, we evaluate the *ternary operator* as is written in the first line.

The ternary operator will first inspect whether `isinstance(y,str)` holds (we check if `y` is a string). If so, we simply add `%s_%s%(x,y)` to the list. If not, we evaluate a list comprehension `['%s_%s'%(x,yi) for yi in y]`. Here we iterate over *every* element `yi` of `y`, and we then add `%s_%s%(x,yi)` to the sublist.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following approch, where you check whether the element in `list2` is a list or not:

```
[[str(x)+'_'+str(el) for el in y] if isinstance(y, list)
 else str(x)+"_"+str(y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
['H1_item1',
 ['H2_item2', 'H2_item3'],
 ['H3_item4', 'H3_item5', 'H3_item6'],
 ['H4_item7', 'H4_item8']]
```

Comment: Lol, we came up with almost the same solution concurrently :)

Comment: race to the millisecond :)